# How to do UI Scaling in Windows 10 When Display Setting is Greyed Out

Tags: command-line, user-interface

I have a 1920 monitor and my laptop thinks it is 1024. So I forced the output to 1920 but the display setting still thinks it is a 1024 monitor so no UI scaling is enabled. I like to know how I can force a UI scaling through command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in command prompt like you did for changing the screenres, but you can use customized scaling also in screen setting found in control panel (not setting). It will allow you to scale regardless of your resolution.

Comment: It worked. Interesting to see windows setting and control panel are two different animals.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might sound stupid, but worked for me. It doesn't use the command prompt, but should be able to achieve what you want.

Right click on your desktop and open "Display settings". The scaling option will probably be greyed out. If you have 2 monitores, click on the other monitor and back again to the monitor you want to change scaling.

When I did this, the option wasn't greyed out anymore and I was able to change it.